# KB968211 hangs on win7

Tags: windows-7, firefox

When I watch a video with Firefox I get constantly a message that I should upgrade my media player leading me to this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968211

If I download and install it, then the installation just hangs.

What can I do to actually install it?

Comment: Unless you don't have Service Pack 1 that download isn't applicable to your system.  Use the correct one instead: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546.  You can always use something other then WMP since your using Windows 7 N or Windows 7 KN that might be easier for you.

Comment: @Ramhound Awesome! So simple and it worked! Thank you. You want to write an answer so I can check it?

Comment: I basically told you to install the correct patch.  That shouldn't be worth any reputation in my opinion.

Comment: @Ramhound okay I understand your view. However, when you google for that question you find as top rank that: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b1658294-3f3e-43d4-852b-f0978772f1a1/installing-media-feature-pack-kb968211-hangs?forum=w7itprogeneral . Its from 2011 and the only answers are: deinstall SP1, then install the package and reinstall SP1 .Installing SP1 was a big time-consuming process and I was just about to format my complete hard drive. I think your comment is worth a lot. at least 17 people didn't manage to solve that problem.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1044528/attempting-to-install-msu-hotfixes-results-in-searching-for-updates-on-this-com/1044548#1044548