# Windows update stand alone pakages (msu) loop

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

The windows update  of my windows 7 sp1 is not working. So i decided to get possible updates as a stand alone packages. i downloaded many  packages. but when i clicked at one of the packages firstly it shows preparing for 1 second then searching for updates on this computer then this thing keeps showing for hrs even i let it doing it over night after still it keeps showing searching for updates. even if the package is of some kbs. is it  bug in my windows that need to fix.
please help to fix this issue

Comment: Try reseting windows update and see if it clears your problem https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058

Comment: Actually both worked  but this one needs only little efforts

Comment: no, setting it to disable breaks MSU install

Answer (score 15, accepted):

stop the Windows Update service (`net stop wuauserv`) before installing a MSU update. I use this cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /R "%~dp0" %%A IN (*Windows6.1-KB*.MSU) DO (
        CALL :SUB %%~nA        
    ECHO= Installing KB!KB_NUM!        
    >NUL net stop wuauserv
    WUSA "%%A" /quiet /norestart)
ECHO= == Press any key to close the Window ==
>NUL PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

:SUB

SET "KB_NUM=%*"
FOR /F "DELIMS=-" %%B IN ("%KB_NUM:*-KB=%") DO SET "KB_NUM=%%B"
```

to enum all MSU updates in the folder where the CMD is stored and install them and before installing an update, it stops the service to speed it up.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution:

1. Go to the Start Menu, type services.msc and press <kbd>Return</kbd>
2. Scroll to find *Windows Update* and double-click
3. Change the startup type from *Automatic* to *Manual* or *Disabled* (whichever you prefer)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @DavidPostill, the first line is a comment, but the rest is a useful (and better) answer.