# How to create a batch file for this issue?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch

I need help making a batch file that will create a folder and then extract a cabinet file from a Windows installer file and then run a DISM command to install said extracted update. Below is a list of the command to use but for the life of me I cannot figure out the batch command order to get it to work.

```
mkdir update
expand -f: Windows6.1-KB3112343-x64.msu .\update
cd update
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:Windows6.1-KB3112343-x64.cab
```

I would be using the command knowing the file is at `C:/users/owner/desktop/Windows6.1-KB3112343-x64`

I'll also be making the update folder on the desktop as well. I just want to automate this process as much as possible because I have many Windows 7 computers that I update and to start I usually need to do the above commands and I want to make it more efficient if I can.

Comment: Why use DISM to install an update to a live machine when you can run the `.msu` file? I would see the point if you were using DISM to service an offline image... p.s. what problem are you having with the script?

Comment: A very large portion of the time when I run the Windows6.1-KB3112343-x64.msu it takes hours to run and I've found extracting the cab file takes 4-5 mintues roughly. I would just like to automate it further. Unfortunately I am not very good with batch so I'm running into issues going to the next steps after creating the update directory. In fact I am really just starting to learn batch and am looking for guidelines on how to proceed in making that batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a [typical XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You tried to fix the slow MSU install and this can be done by [running this batch file](https://superuser.com/a/1057487/174557). It stops the Windows Update service before trying to install a MSU update. This speeds up the installation a lot.