# Win7 x64 Pro Fresh stuck on Installing KB3020369

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I've got a new PC from Lenovo and it is just hanging when installing KB3020369. I have tried a heap of troubleshooting steps including using wsusoffline, but it is still stuck.

I can't find any logs for why it's stuck on this msu in event viewer or WindowsUpdate.log (the latter may be irrelevant when using wsusoffline).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers

Comment: stop Windows Update service before installing a MSU (http://superuser.com/a/1057487/174557)

Answer (score 0):

I had [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/1176907/630402).

Per this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1177234/630402):

> ...reset all the Windows Update, that way it will start anew. You can
>   use [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-Windows-Update-Agent-d824badc).  Run it As Administrator, use option 2 and 3,
>   and when finished restart the PC.
>
> If that does not help, I would suggest you trying to delete the
>   registry key
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersio‌n\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired` (export it first to have a backup) and restart
>   the PC again.